# Clarification on the definition of $X^{\omega}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have never seen this notation before (graduated with a math degree a few months ago; not in school currently). Here's what I gather from Munkres' *Topology*:

> Given a set $X$, an $\mathbf{\omega}$ **-tuple** of elements of $X$
>   is a function \begin{equation*} \mathbf{x}: \mathbb{N} \to
>  X\text{.} \end{equation*} Such a function is called a **sequence** or
>   **infinite sequence** of elements of $X$. The $i$th value of $\mathbf{x}$ at $i$ is $x_i$, known as the $i$**th coordinate** of
>   $\mathbf{x}$ and denote \begin{equation*} \mathbf{x} =
>  \left(x_1, x_2, \dots\right) = \left(x_n\right)_{n \in
>  \mathbb{N}}\text{.} \end{equation*}

As an example, Munkres mentions $X^{\omega}$, where $X = \{0, 1\}$. What *is* $X^{\omega}$ in this case? The set of all $\omega$-tuples where each coordinate can either be a $0$ or $1$? So am I correct in thinking that 
$$X^{\omega} = \{(x_1, \dots, x_{\omega}): x_i = 0 \text{ or }1\}\text{?}$$
Can $\omega$ be finite, as well as infinite?

Comment: I think X^omega means the set of all omega-tuples of the elements of X. I don't think omega can be finite (because it's the natural numbers).